# Lua Tables Assigning values to key in tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

Um what's the difference between in assigning values:

```
Lesson["Maths"] = {grade = 10, class = 3}
```

and

```
Lesson["Maths"] = {["grade"] = 10, ["class"] = 3}
```

Which one should I go if I want to assign a value to a key in a table? Or which one is more used? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, both of them are the same. The first usage fails when you want keys with special characters in them:

```
tEx = {
  failed-approach = true,
}
```

The code segment above will result in an error and you would be forced to follow the second method of creating keys:

```
tEx = {
  ['failed-approach'] = false,
}
```

Both of the approaches are same and it doesn't matter which one you wish to use.

Comment: Note that any expression can be used inside of the brackets, not just a string. You can do variable references, math, function calls, etc.

Comment: Also, note that the bracket-less syntax is for string keys that are valid Lua identifiers.